# XSLT - Key() function

Tags: xslt, key, iteration

I'm a bit confused about this key function:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="article[count(. | key('idkey', @id)[1]) = 1]>
```

Is there anyone that can briefly explain whats happening in this for-each loop?

The key is: `<xsl:key name="idkey" match="/newspapers/newspaper" use="@id"/>`

@id is an attribute in newspaper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `key('idkey', @id)[1]` selects the first element whose idkey is equal to @id.

The expression `count(A|B) = 1` is an insane XSLT 1.0 workaround for testing whether A and B are the same node. (You will also see people using `generate-id(A)=generate-id(B)` for this.)

Put these together and you are asking whether the current element is the first one in the document that has a particular id value.

This is the basis of the technique called Muenchian Grouping (which becomes redundant in XSLT 2.0).

There is something fishy about the code because the key seems to be matching newspaper id's, not article id's. But perhaps they are related in some way.

Answer (score -1):

In this `for-each` element

```
<xsl:for-each select="article[count(. | key('idkey', @id)[1]) = 1]">
```

The `for-each` is being applied to the *first* `article` element for each  `@id` attribute.

- The call `key('idkey', @id)` is selecting all `article` elements with the same `@id` attribute as the current one.
- `key('idkey', @id)[1]` selects the *first* of all `article` elements with the same `@id`.
- Because a node cannot appear in a node set more than once, the union `. | key('idkey', @id)[1]` will contain *one* node if the current `article` is the same node as the *first* `article` with the same `@id`. Otherwise it will contain *two*.
- Checking that the value of `count()` is one selects only the elements that are the first with any `@id`.

An alternative way of doing this, and the one I prefer, is to use `generate-id` like this

```
select="article[generate-id() = generate-id(key('idkey', @id)[1])]"
```

which checks directly whether the current element is the same one as the first element in the set by comparing their generated IDs.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong here because the key **idkey** is not a key for article/@id it is newspaper/@id. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: @hr_117: While writing that I was wishing that the OP had shown the declaration for `idkey`. Somehow I overlooked it. But the way things are, the `select` XPath is very odd because, since no nodeset returned by `key()` can contain an `article` element, the predicate is the same as `1 + count(key('idkey', @id)[1]) = 1` or, as you say, `not(key('idkey', @id))`. This is clearly a bug.